# How to force removal of kubernetes cluster on GitLab?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I'm trying to remove a Kubernetes cluster - with "Remove integration and resources" from my GitLab repo.

Helm tiller gives me this info:

```
Something went wrong while uninstalling Helm Tiller
Kubernetes error:
```

The `Integration status` is disabled.
That means the connection to my K8s cluster doesn't exist.
The K8s cluster to which GitLab was connected to before, doesn't exist anymore!

Is there a way to force the deletion of a K8s cluster on GitLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue:

Instead of choosing "Remove integration and resource," you need to select "Remove integration."

After I've had chosen this option and pushed the button, the K8s cluster was gone!